# PHP, como eu faço para quando o numero depois do . for 0 ficar oculto?

Tags: php

Boa Noite

Eu tenho um valor exemplo 100.00 e 100.30, na minha tabela no meu BD, como eu faço para dar um echo quando os números forem 00 depois do ponto ficar ocultos exemplo 100.00 mostrar 100 e se for 100.30, mostrar normal para usuário.

eu pensei em usar `IF` e o `number_format`, mas não tenho certeza se esse modo mais correto ou existe um caminho mais fácil.

Obrigado

Comment: Já tem uma resposta para esta pergunta no stackoverflow em inglês. http://stackoverflow.com/q/14531679/2370479

Comment: Exato. Dê uma olhada na função floatval()

Comment: Boa Noite é isso mesmo, obrigado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 100.30 +0 retorna 100.3 e acho que o que se quer é "se for 100.30, mostrar normal para usuário".

PHP

```
    $acheme=".00";
    $meunumero=$_POST['numero'];

    $pos = strpos($meunumero, $acheme);

    if ($pos === false) {
        echo $meunumero;
    } else {
        echo substr($meunumero,0,-3);
        //ou se preferir use
        //echo $meunumero+0;
    }
```

HTML

```
<form name='form' method=post action='' >
    <input type="text" name="numero" class="nome1" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="testar">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

## Formatando com tipo float

Quando a variável não possuir o valor dentro de aspas, os ZEROs a direita são omitidos "automaticamente"

```
$n = 100.00;
echo $n; // retorna 100

$n = 100.30;
echo $n; // retorna 100.3
```

Quando é delimitado por aspas simples ou aspas duplas, é tratado como string no momento de imprimir. Os exemplos acima retornariam 100.00 e 100.30, repectivamente.

Portanto, se não é importante exibir o zero quando há um valor fracionário, 100.30, basta não delinmitar com aspas.

Caso não seja possível, é preciso fazer um cast.

Há formas variadas que retornam o mesmo resultado:

```
$n = '100.30';
echo (float)$n; // retorna 100.3

$n = '100.30';
echo floatval($n); // retorna 100.3

$n = '100.30';
echo $n + 0; // retorna 100.3

$n = '100.30';
echo +$n; // retorna 100.3
```

<sub>*A opção mais "bonitinha" ou mais "curta" não quer dizer que seja mais rápida.</sub>

## Formatando o tipo string

Se ainda assim quer exibir o zero a direita de um valor fracionário, uma opção é fazer uma formatação que identifique tal condição.

```
// O valor pode ser número ou string
//$n = '100.00';
//$n = 100.00;
//$n = '100.30';
$n = 100.30;

// Garante que a formatação mantenha 2 casas decimais
$n = number_format($n, 2, '.', '');

// Abstrai a parte decimal
$d = substr($n, -2);

// Se for 00, então, faz o cast para removê-los
if ($d === '00') {
    $n = (float)$n;
}

// Imprime o resultado
echo $n;
```

De uma forma mais resumida, pode fazer apenas isso

```
$n = str_replace('.00', '', number_format($n, 2, '.', ''));
echo $n;
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o `str_replace`, dessa forma:

```
str_replace('.00', '', $numero);
```

Isto irá remover o `.00` se houver, se não for encontrado o `.00` nenhuma mudança será feita.

```
Entrada:   100.00
Resultado: 100

Entrada:   100.30
Resultado: 100.30

Entrada:   1
Resultado: 1

Entrada:   1.01
Resultado: 1.01
```

**[Teste isto aqui.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/93a123f637eb4547ccdcf8c1b9076025cdc47f61)**

Answer (score 0):

A forma mais simples que eu vejo é verificar se o valor é numericamente igual ao *type cast* para `int` dele, pois `"123.00" == (int) "123.00"` returna `true`, enquanto `"123.10" == (int) "123.10"` returna `false`. Desta forma:

```
$number = "123.00";
echo ($number == (int) $number) ? (int) $number : $number, PHP_EOL;
// 123

$number = "123.10";
echo ($number == (int) $number) ? (int) $number : $number, PHP_EOL;
// 123.10

$number = "123.1000";
echo ($number == (int) $number) ? (int) $number : $number, PHP_EOL;
// 123.1000
```

Funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/P3amPX).